# Get data about attractions and point of interest from DBpedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I don't know how to use DBpedia or SPARQL.

Could you please help me in finding data list of attractions and point of interest from DBpedia.

Actually I want Hotels and Tourist Places from all Cities/Country with Latitude, Longitude, attraction Name, Location Name, City, State, continents, etc.

Please Help me to get data using Query of SPARQL.

If you have any other suggestion then please guide me..

Comment: This looks a great deal like a homework assignment, and it closely resembles many past questions found on this site.

Comment: @IrshadKhan What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used http://data.plan4all.eu/sparql for fetching data of Tourist Places.
For Ex: construct { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin> ?p ?o .
  ?s ?p2 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin>.
} 
where { 
  { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin> ?p ?o } 
  union 
  { ?s ?p2 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin> } 
}

Sir, I want complete list of Tourist Places / Attractions with there lat-long, City name, Country Name

Comment: How can i get all the cities in the world and their respective attractions
-or- How to get city's famous landmarks

Comment: How to get all Tourist Places or point-of-interest for Mumbai City only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the endpoint: http://dbpedia.org/sparql/

To get all the hotels in Syria:

```
select * where {
?hotel a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Hotel> .
?hotel dbo:location dbr:Syria
}
```

This answer is just to give you an idea how to query DBPedia

#### Update

After you comment *Suppose I want to get all Tourist Places or point-of-interest for Mumbai City only*

You should define what those "Tourist Places* are? In the below query, I gave you an example, assuming the tourist places are museums, towers, parks, churches, Skyscrapers,

```
select ?thing ?type ?typeName where {

VALUES ?city {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/London>}

?thing dbo:location ?city.

optional 
{
?thing a ?type .
VALUES ?type {<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Hotel>}
BIND( "Hotel" as ?typeName )
}

optional
{
?thing a ?type.
VALUES ?type {dbo:Museum}
BIND( "Museum" as ?typeName )
}
optional
{
?thing a ?type.
VALUES ?type {dbo:Pyramid}
BIND( "Pyramid" as ?typeName )
}

optional
{
?thing a ?type.
VALUES ?type {yago:Skyscraper104233124}
BIND( "Skyscraper" as ?typeName )
}

optional
{
?thing a ?type.
VALUES ?type {dbo:Park}
BIND( "Park" as ?typeName )
}

optional
{
?thing a ?type.
VALUES ?type {yago:Church103028079}
BIND( "Church" as ?typeName )
}

{
?thing a dbo:Place
}

filter (BOUND (?type))

}
```

If you get the idea you can extend it

Update 2

You wanted to show long, lat and country. Here you go:

```
select ?thing ?type ?typeName ?long ?lat ?country where {

VALUES ?city {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/London>}

optional {
?city dbo:country ?country
}

?thing dbo:location ?city.

optional 
{
?thing a ?type .
VALUES ?type {<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Hotel>}
BIND( "Hotel" as ?typeName )
}

optional
{
?thing a ?type.
VALUES ?type {dbo:Museum}
BIND( "Museum" as ?typeName )
}
optional
{
?thing a ?type.
VALUES ?type {dbo:Pyramid}
BIND( "Pyramid" as ?typeName )
}

optional
{
?thing a ?type.
VALUES ?type {yago:Skyscraper104233124}
BIND( "Skyscraper" as ?typeName )
}

optional
{
?thing a ?type.
VALUES ?type {dbo:Park}
BIND( "Park" as ?typeName )
}

optional
{
?thing a ?type.
VALUES ?type {yago:Church103028079}
BIND( "Church" as ?typeName )
}

optional
{
?thing geo:long ?long.
?thing geo:lat ?lat
}


{
?thing a dbo:Place
}

filter (BOUND (?type))

}
```

Comment: thanks ... but it showing few top hotels only.  I want complete list of hotels with there lat long, city, and area location

Comment: I want list of all Tourist Places or Attractions from city. 
That list must have Place name, Lat-Long, City name, Country Name.

as below example is providing list of SoccerPlayer with BirthDate and Height

 SELECT * WHERE {
  ?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SoccerPlayer> .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?birthDate .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/height> ?height .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/position> ?position .
}

Comment: @IrshadKhan it doesn't work like that. There is no *must* here. You are consuming data from dbpedia. if dbpedia doesn't have it, you won't have it. Plus, please be specific, what kind of Attractions? hotels? swimming pools? museums? ...

Comment: Could you please tell me, How to Get data for city only.

Suppose I want to get all Tourist Places or point-of-interest for Mumbai City only.

Comment: Thanks.. may I know how to add or show latitude, Longitude and Country on Updated Result